# How do I dynamically set a WheelJoint's anchor points?

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I've created a car in RUBE and imported it into my game. The game has a tuning menu, allowing the ride height of the car to be adjusted with a slider.

I can't work out how to change the position of the `WheelJoint` relative to the car body. The result I'm looking for is as if I had changed the `anchorA` Y-value in RUBE. I thought this would be equivalent, but it isn't:

```
    car.rearWheelJoint.getAnchorA().set(xvalue,yvalue);
```

I've tried instead creating a whole new jointdef:

```
        WheelJointDef d = new WheelJointDef();

        d.initialize(car.rearWheelJoint.getBodyA(), car.rearWheelJoint.getBodyB(),
                car.rearWheelJoint.getAnchorA().add(0,(val-100)*0.01f), 
                car.rearWheelJoint.getAnchorB());

        car.rearWheelJoint = (WheelJoint) game.world.createJoint(d);
```

...but I think this is messing up the pointer to the wheel joint.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to change the wheel joint anchor?

Comment: to increase the ride height of the car, I have a tune menu where you use a slider to adjust it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly, no, you cannot change the anchor point dynamically. You only destroy the joint and re-create it.

---

You should be able to change other joint parameters at run-time though.

In real life the ride height of a car is determined by the equilibrium position reached by the springs:

> m*g = k*x

where m is the mass of the car body, g is the acceleration due to gravity, and k is the spring coefficient. You can solve this for x:

> x = m*g/k

Our goal is to minimize x. We can't change g without affecting other parts of the simulation, and we can't change m [without destroying the fixture](http://box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=6089), so we need to edit k.

Unfortunately box2d does not let us edit the spring coefficient directly. But we do know that the natural frequency of a 1D mass-spring-damper system is:

> w = sqrt(k/m)

and we do have control over the natural frequency, w. So if we increase w then k must increase. When k increases, x decreases (inverse relationship).

Below is the result when I vary the natural frequency of the wheel joints in RUBE:
[image]
From left to right the natural frequencies are 2, 5, and 10.

Note that increasing the spring stiffness also changes the car dynamics as well as the ride height. Stiffer springs result in a bumpier ride. This may be desirable for your game.

If you really want to try and limit the ride height to an aesthetic change then you need to use a distance joint and revolute joint:

[image]

For each of the above unicycles, the wheel is connected via a revolute joint to the intermediate body (small square). That intermediate body is connected to the 'car' body with a prismatic joint and a distance joint. The setup is almost identical to before, except we have control over one more parameter: the length. The length parameter specifies the equilibrium position of the spring (distance joint). In libgdx this parameter can be set with the [`DistanceJoint::setLength`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/joints/DistanceJoint.html#setLength%28float%29) public member function.

Finally, keep in mind that if you do go the distance joint route, you will still be changing the angular dynamics of your car (i.e. a longer distance joint length or ride height will raise the center of gravity, making it more likely to flip over).

Comment: thanks, I've gone the distance/prismatic joint route because I want to modify the joint suspension rigidity to.